# Promise.race: время жизни "проигравшего(их)" промиса(ов)

Tags: javascript

Что происходит с остальными промисами, которые проиграли в "гонке"? Удаляются ли они из контекста исполнения?

Answer (score 1):

Ничего. Промисы вообще неотменяемы. Так что отлично живут пока не закончатся.

Comment: Т.е. любые "зависшие" промисы - это камень в огород контекста исполнения?

Comment: @Kayrosik, что значит "зависшие"?

Comment: время ичполнения которых, слишклм великл, например, асинхронный запрос в редис, который в процессе запоса упал

Comment: Если он упал, то он не завис.